# Query using group by but only displaying the latest entry for each item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm working on a spreadsheet that records logistics reports via a Google form. We have 100 locations and logistics personal visit and report on condition of each location, i.e. the location needs maintenance etc.

We have 3 categories of location: Priority locations that need to be visited daily, secondary locations that need to be visited a minimum every other day, and other locations that we aim to visit a minimum of every 3 days.

Each logistics visit is recorded in the spreadsheet via the form it captures:

```
Column A = Time Stamp,  
Column B = Location,  
Column C = Damage Yes/No,  
Column D = Damage Description,  
Column E = Personnel ID,
```

I want to create a query that groups the entries by location so that only the last visit for each location is displayed.

And use conditional formatting relating to latest visit date to highlight:
Green visited today,
Amber visited yesterday,
Red visited three days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query is not an option for your task, try this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B,B2:B<>"")),QUERY(SORT(A2:E,1,false),
"select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4, Col5"),{2,1,3,4,5},0))
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great. @MaxMakhrov It works but the dates are displaying as numbers rather than time stamps.   Perhaps it's important to note that the time stamp is Date and time DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS.  If I don't want to do it on the main sheet, I'd rather import the data into another tab and do it there, to protect the original data. Can I use importrange or a named range.  Is it possible to insert group by into this query?  =QUERY(
   LogisticsReports,
   "SELECT A,B,J WHERE A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()-7,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",
   1
)

Comment: dates are numbers. You may change formatting to `date` to display them properly

Comment: Is there a way to put this =ArrayFormula in a separate tab using importrange or a Named Range?

Comment: Yes, you may use it in any combination with other functions